# Putting values into multidimensional mixed array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have the following mixed array in js:

```
  var MY_INFO = {
       'NAME' : ['input1', 'inpu2', 'input3']
  };
```

I need to push values into this format. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Realized that my question was not specific enough.

So, I have 4 specific data:

1. Name
2. Input1
3. Input2
4. Input3

The function is :

```
function push_my_info(name,input1,input2,input3){
    var MY_INFO = {
       name : [input1, input2, input3]
    };
}
```

Something like this..

However, bit confused to how to `push` it properly so there can be multiple "top" objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var MY_INFO = {
       'NAME' : ['input1', 'inpu2', 'input3']
};

MY_INFO.NAME.push('whatever I want!');

console.log(MY_INFO.NAME);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

You can use push:

`MY_INFO.NAME.push('whatever I want!');`